# Is there an easy way to use jQuery to fade in a css :hover background?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have an IMG with CSS that uses :hover to show a background.  Is there an easy way to use jQuery to fade in the background instead of it instantly appearing?

My current code is:

```
HTML: <img id="home-logo" src="path/logo-home.png">`
CSS: #home-logo:hover { background: url(path/logo-back.png) right bottom no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Yes. Put the background on a different element and fade in that element. Background image opacity isn't supported by any browser or JavaScript library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment/idea.  I'll play around with that concept some.  Question though: I can get it to fade in and out when I hover over it, but how do I get it to load transparent and the fade in with the hover?

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks for your help eyelidlessness, your suggestions helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and found the best way to do this was to use two images instead of a background:

```
HTML:
    <img id="home-link" src="path/logo.gif"><img id="home-fade" src="path/logo-fade.gif">

CSS:
    #home-link { cursor:pointer; }
    #home-fade { display:none; }

JS:
    $(document.body).hover(function () {
          $("#home-fade").fadeIn('slow');
        },function(){
          $("#home-fade").fadeOut('slow');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes!!! you can use THIS...

```
$('#home-logo').hover(function(){
  $(this).fadeIn('slow', function() {
  //do something  
  });
 });
```

for further information you should look at this tutorial.[**fadeIn**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to fade your opacity, in that case you can use fadeTo method.
first argument is duration or speed, second argument is value of opacity.

JQUERY CODE:

```
    $('#home-logo').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.2);
    },
    function(){
      $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    });
```

HTML CODE:

```
<img id="home-logo" src="path/logo-home.png">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jowan/3Ek88/1/)

Comment: Thanks.  I played around with it some.  This works great with fading the image, but not the background unfortunately.